# Usage of document.getElementsByClassName in a different path

Tags: javascript, directory

I have my JavaScript file located in a different folder, so right now it can't find the class that it's looking for. I'd like it to know the path of the class while being in a separate folder.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing whatsoever to do with path

Perhaps you load the script in the head before the slideshow html exists.

Try

```
var slideIndex = 0;
window.addEventListener("load",showSlides);
```